# What is the right way to define attributes in python

Tags: python, class, attributes

what is the different between

```
class d():
    d = None
    def __init__(self):
        .....
```

and:

```
class d():
   def __init__(self):
       self.d = None
```

Comment: Also good answers regarding 1st case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python